# Google area chart - make vertical section

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Im working on a graph it should basically be a graph like the one iv'e posted below - i need to make a closed section only "verified users" can access and the design is close to the picture below:

[image: Closed section graph]

Here is where i got so far in dataset:

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Past', 'Future'],
      ['2013',  1000,      null],
      ['2014',  1170,      null],
      ['2015',  660,       660],
      ['2016',  null,      540]
    ]);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fv6d0hsj/

Comment: I can remove the data, but i still need to have the visual representation of a closed off area